# Meaning of the number argument inside of an index, R

Tags: r, indexing

I am very new to R. I have the following code.

```
polls <- polls[str_detect(polls$remain, "%"), -9]
```

What is the meaning of "-9"?
Thank you

Comment: It means except the `9th` column, select all other columns

Comment: Can you provide any resources which I can learn more about [ ] arguments? Thank you.